# Chain addition mod 10

Tags: calculations

Is it possible in LaTeX create a table-like structure that represents successive modulo-10 addition of the individual units modulo 10 *with* wrap-around? This is referred to as chain-addition.

For example, starting with 123456, chain adding, we have

```
┌───────── transfer ─ over ─────────┐
|                                   |
|                                   v
1   ┌ 2   ┌ 3   ┌ 4   ┌ 5   ┌ 6   ┌ 1
├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘
3     5     7     9     1     7
```

(when addition is made modulo 10) to obtain 357917. Chain-adding again we have

```
┌───────── transfer ─ over ─────────┐
|                                   |
|                                   v
3   ┌ 5   ┌ 7   ┌ 9   ┌ 1   ┌ 7   ┌ 3
├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘ ├─+─┘
8     2     6     0     8     0
```

(when addition is made modulo 10) to obtain 826080. Tabularizing this we have:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
3 5 7 9 1 7
8 2 6 0 8 0
0 8 6 8 8 8
. . . . . .
```

and so on and so on.

You'll notice its add without carrying, so mod 10.

I want to be able to just input the starting number and generate a table with the other numbers

I know you can do math calculations in LaTeX, but I'm not sure where to begin with this for being able to choose initial input.

Comment: ok, so i edited the above to correct the formatting. thank you!

Comment: 3+5=8, thus starting the chain that gives you the second line, then 8+2=0, giving you the second line

Comment: I took some ASCII art liberties to clarify the question...

Answer (score 12):

A job for spreadtab:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{*6{c}}}
\SThiderow 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\STcopy{>5,v}{a1+b1-10*trunc((a1+b1)/10,0)}&&&&&\STcopy{v}{a1+f1-10*trunc((a1+f1)/10,0)}\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great package !

Answer (score 11):

**second update** adds the automatic determination of the final cycle. Added at bottom of answer.

**first update** adds the tabulars : I wasn't sure exactly what was meant by `table`, thus the first version simply outputted the digit chains as successive paragraphs. The version with a tabular is at bottom of answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\modten}[1]{\the\numexpr #1+10-((#1+5)/10)*10\relax}

\makeatletter
% expandable implementation
% #1 = initial string
% #2 number of reps
\newcommand*{\chainadd}[2]{#1\endgraf\chainadd@i {#2}#1\relax }

\def\chainadd@i #1#2#3\relax {\ifnum #1=0 \expandafter\@gobble\else
                              \expandafter\@firstofone \fi
      {\expandafter\chainadd@ii\expandafter{\the\numexpr #1-1}{}#2#3#2\relax }}

\def\chainadd@ii #1#2#3#4{\ifx\relax #4\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
                       \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
   {#2\endgraf\chainadd@i {#1}#2\relax}%
   {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\chainadd@iii\modten{#3+#4}{#2}{#1}#4}}

\def\chainadd@iii #1#2#3{\chainadd@ii {#3}{#2#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chainadd {123456}{10}

\bigskip

\chainadd {1234567}{10}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

Code for presentation of output as tabular rows : I wasn't sure whether or not the input data was to be or not the first row of the output. Besides here the number of columns in the tabular has to be given by the user, if needed one could modify `\chainadd` to not only produce the rows but also the `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` with the suitable tabular template.

As the core implementation is expandable `\chainadd` inserts itself most easily in a tabular.

As in the first implementation `\chainadd` has two arguments the first one is a chain of decimal digits of arbitrary length, the second is the number of time the process has to be repeated. The initial data makes the first row of the output. Then there are as many additional rows as requested by the second argument to `\chainadd`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\modten}[1]{\the\numexpr #1+10-((#1+5)/10)*10\relax}

\makeatletter

% expandable implementation
% #1 = initial string
% #2 number of reps

% Update with added \ChainRow to prepare tabular rows

\newcommand*{\chainadd}[2]{\ChainRow{#1}\chainadd@i {#2}#1\relax }

\def\chainadd@stop #1\relax {}

\def\chainadd@i #1#2#3\relax {\ifnum #1=\z@\expandafter\chainadd@stop\fi
    \expandafter\chainadd@ii\expandafter{\the\numexpr #1-\@ne}{}#2#3#2\relax }

\def\chainadd@ii #1#2#3#4{\ifx\relax #4\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
                       \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
   {\ChainRow{#2}\chainadd@i {#1}#2\relax}%
   {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\chainadd@iii\modten{#3+#4}{#2}{#1}#4}}

\def\chainadd@iii #1#2#3{\chainadd@ii {#3}{#2#1}}

\newcommand*{\ChainRow}[1]{\chainrow@i #1\relax}

\def\chainrow@i  #1{#1\chainrow@ii }

\def\chainrow@ii #1{\ifx\relax #1\expandafter\@firstoftwo
                    \else 
                    \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                    {\\}{&#1\chainrow@ii}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
  \hline
  \chainadd {123456}{10}
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
  \hline
  \chainadd {1234567}{10}
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: chain additions, tabular form]

---

And now for the automatic determination of the period of the iterative process.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\modten}[1]{\the\numexpr #1+10-((#1+5)/10)*10\relax}

\makeatletter
% Looking for the cycle.
\def\gobtoexclam #1!{}

\newcommand*{\chainiterate}[1]
    {\romannumeral0\expandafter\chainiterate@i\romannumeral-`0#1!}
\def\chainiterate@i #1#2!{\chainiterate@ii {}#1#2#1!}
\def\chainiterate@ii #1#2#3{\gobtoexclam #3\chainiterate@end!%
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\chainiterate@iii \modten{#2+#3}#3{#1}}
\def\chainiterate@iii #1#2#3{\chainiterate@ii {#3#1}#2}
\def\chainiterate@end!#1!#2{ #2}
% 
\newcommand*{\chainiteratetwice}[1]
    {\romannumeral-`0\chainiterate{\chainiterate{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\ChainCycle}{}
\newcommand*{\ChainCycleStart}{}

\newcommand*{\odef}[1]{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter}

\newcommand*{\oodef}[1]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                        \def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter 
                        #1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter }

\def\FindCycle@DefTest #1{%
    \def\FindCycle@DoTest ##1,#1,##2##3?%
        {\if!##2\expandafter 0\else\expandafter 1\fi }%
}%

\newcommand*{\FindCycle}[1]{%
    \odef\FindCycle@X {#1}%
    \let\FindCycle@Y\FindCycle@X 
    \loop
        \oodef\FindCycle@X{\chainiterate{\FindCycle@X}}%
        \oodef\FindCycle@Y{\chainiteratetwice{\FindCycle@Y}}%
    \ifx\FindCycle@X\FindCycle@Y\else
    \repeat
    \odef\ChainCycle {\expandafter,\FindCycle@X}%
    \loop
        \oodef\FindCycle@Y{\chainiterate{\FindCycle@Y}}%
    \ifx\FindCycle@Y\FindCycle@X\else
        \oodef\ChainCycle {\expandafter\ChainCycle\expandafter,\FindCycle@Y}%
    \repeat
    \count@ \z@
    \odef\FindCycle@X {#1}%
    \loop
       \expandafter\FindCycle@DefTest\expandafter{\FindCycle@X}%
    % is this iterate in the cycle ?
    \if0\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\FindCycle@DoTest
           \expandafter\ChainCycle\expandafter,\FindCycle@X,!?%
    % no, it isn't
      \oodef\FindCycle@X {\chainiterate{\FindCycle@X}}%
      \advance\count@\@ne
    \repeat
    The first iterate of #1 which starts the period is obtained after
    \the\count@{} iteration{\ifnum\count@>1 s\fi}. It is \FindCycle@X.\par
    \count@\z@
    \let\FindCycle@Y\FindCycle@X
    Here is the period: \FindCycle@X
    \loop
       \advance\count@\@ne
       \oodef\FindCycle@Y {\chainiterate{\FindCycle@Y}}%
    \ifx\FindCycle@Y\FindCycle@X
    \else
    , \FindCycle@Y
    \repeat
    .\par Its length is \the\count@.\par
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\FindCycle {12}
\bigskip

\FindCycle {123}
\bigskip

\FindCycle {1234}
\bigskip

\FindCycle {12345}
\bigskip

\FindCycle {123456}
\bigskip

% SURPRISE !
\FindCycle {1234567}

\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]

---

[image: page 2]

---

[image: page 3]

Comment: algorithmic note: the first `k` such as the `k` th and `2k` th iterates coincide is necessarily a multiple `qP` of the period `P`. Once we get `k` we can get `P` during the construction of `\ChainCycle`. Then the initial stretch `s` is at least `>k-P`. Thus we can gain in efficiency in not testing belongness to cycle of the first `k-P` iterate. But here in practice the initial stretches before entering a cycle proved short. Thus I do not edit the code, but wanted to signal this slight defect.

Comment: For the fun, let me mention that with `123456789` the period has length `3906` (and starts with iterate `1`). And with `1234578901` which has 11 digits, the period starts immediately and has length `96844`. The print-out took `351` pages... the `TeX` computation was quite lengthy (perhaps 15 or 20 minutes, I didn't time it and left my computer on its own after a few minutes; when I came back computation was done).

Comment: Didn't try but `\def\addmodten#1#2{\expandafter\@gobble\number\numexpr1#1+1#2\relax}` is probably faster, specially for long computations.

Comment: @unbonpetit yes I agree; and using `\the` rather than `\number` would make it a tiny tiny bit faster yet (or at least I believe so, I tested `\the` vz `\number` with `\numexpr` about 2 years ago I think; but here it is even more specialized). The faster would simply be to store all possible one digit mod 10 additions in macros: `\csname addmodten#1#2\endcsname`.

Comment: I meant that gobbling the fisrt digit of `\numexpr1<a>+1<b>` (where `<a>` and `<b>` are digits) is faster than your `\modten{<a>+<b>}` macro since it involves a mulitplication and a division.

Comment: @unbonpetit I understood (and do agree with) what you meant! and as I said the fastest is surely to define first 100 macros holding the results of all these digit + digit mod 10 operations.

Answer (score 9):

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\chain}{mm}
 {% #1 is the starting number, #2 is the number of repetitions
  \egreg_chain_add:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_egreg_chain_tablebody_tl
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_chain_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_chain_output_seq
\int_new:N \l_egreg_chain_length_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_chain_add:nn #1 #2
 {
  % form the first input sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_egreg_chain_input_seq { } { #1 }
  % the number of columns for the table
  \int_set:Nn \l_egreg_chain_length_int { \seq_count:N \l_egreg_chain_input_seq }
  % start building the table body
  \tl_clear:N \l_egreg_chain_tablebody_tl
  % first row with the input number
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_chain_tablebody_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_egreg_chain_input_seq { & } \exp_not:N \\
   }
  % repeat as many times as requested
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 }
   {
    % clear the output sequence
    \seq_clear:N \l_egreg_chain_output_seq
    % build the output sequence
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_egreg_chain_input_seq - 1 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_chain_output_seq
       {
        \int_to_arabic:n
         {
          \int_mod:nn
           {
            \seq_item:Nn \l_egreg_chain_input_seq { ##1 } +
            \seq_item:Nn \l_egreg_chain_input_seq { ##1 + 1 }
           }
           { 10 }
         }
       }
     }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_chain_output_seq
     {
      \int_to_arabic:n
       {
        \int_mod:nn
         {
          \seq_item:Nn \l_egreg_chain_input_seq { -1 } +
          \seq_item:Nn \l_egreg_chain_input_seq { 1 }
         }
         { 10 }
       }
     }
    % fill the next row
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_egreg_chain_tablebody_tl
     {
      \seq_use:Nn \l_egreg_chain_output_seq { & } \exp_not:N \\
     }
    % the output sequence becomes the input sequence for the next row
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l_egreg_chain_input_seq \l_egreg_chain_output_seq
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{\l_egreg_chain_length_int}{c}}
  % deliver the table body
  \l_egreg_chain_tablebody_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chain{123456}{10}

\bigskip

\chain{42}{5}

\end{document}
```

The table is built step by step using two sequences; at each step, the output sequence becomes the input sequence for the next step.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding a snippet created in LuaTeX and a preview of the result.

```
% lualatex mal-cells.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
function malcompute() -- the core of computations
counter=0 -- number of columns
series={} -- actual values will be stored here
seriesdata=tex.toks[1] -- get data from TeX and parse them:
for entry in unicode.utf8.gmatch(seriesdata, "%d+") do
   counter=counter+1 -- move to the column+1
   series[counter]=entry -- save data to a Lua table
end -- for, entry
rows=tonumber(tex.toks[2]) -- how many lines is requested?

for row=1,rows do -- we need this number of rows and...
  for column=1,#series do -- ... and columns
    if column==1 then firstvalue=series[1] end -- repeat the computation from the beginning when you reach the last column
    newvalue=(series[column]+(series[column+1] or firstvalue)) % 10 -- get two numbers above the actual one, modulus is a percent sign in Lua
    tex.print(newvalue) -- print the result to TeX
    series[column]=newvalue -- store a new value instead of an old one
    end -- for, column
    tex.print("\\par") -- break a line when there is a new row coming
  end -- for, row
end -- function, malcompute
\end{luacode*}

\def\malcells#1#2{% pass arguments to Lua
   \toks1{#1}% initial values
   \toks2{#2}% number of rows
   \directlua{malcompute()}% get us to the Lua world
   } % End of the \malcells command.

% A small piece of code formatting the results at a TeX level
\ttfamily\Large

% An example as OP asked.
\malcells{1 2 3 4 5 6}{3}   

\end{document}
```

[image: an example of the result]